# Corrupted SignalR SQL backplane database

Tags: sql-server, signalr, signalr-backplane

I'm running an asp.net MVC application that uses signalr,and I'm running signalR off of the SQL server backplane ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server ). I was having some issues with this setup earlier, and one of my developers deleted the 'aspstate' database and re-ran aspnet_regsql to 'clear things out' in his mind.
Unfortunately that seems to have mucked things up even further, and I don't know how to fix it.  Now i'm getting the following error:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_executesql',
>   database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'. Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK__Schema__04D490DBAD491E7F'. Cannot insert duplicate key
>   in object 'SignalR.Schema'. The duplicate key value is (1). Installing
>   SignalR SQL objects Database schema [SignalR] already exists Table
>   [SignalR].[Schema] already exists Installing schema version 1 Mesage
>   table [SignalR].[Messages_0] already exists Message ID table
>   [SignalR].[Messages_0_Id] alread exists The statement has been
>   terminated. Schema version 1 installed SignalR SQL objects installed

I've tried deleting this database and pointing it to a new one, but no luck at all, it feels like something is cached and nothing i do will clear it out.  Are there any ideas how to approach this?  Been beating my head at this for a while, and no amount of reboots/resets/rebuilds has fixed it.

Comment: Does it work on either of the notes in the availability group? I'm not going to be much help in the SignalR side but I'm a database guy so might be able to help there.

Comment: no it doesn't.  I'm not entirely sure the issue is AG related, but thought it should be mentioned.  I think the main issue is the fact that i tried to clear it out before in order to fix another unrelated issue, which might have caused this.  I deleted all the contents inside the signalr databases (there are 3 of them), but maybe the schema id it's looking for above is cached somewhere, or in a temp database?

Comment: When does the db error occur, at app startup, during an insert?

Comment: During the insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so apparently the answer ended up being that the DB admin hadn't granted the user that accessed the signalR databases execute permission.  Says so right in the error, but i just assumed it was there.  Oh well!